# Using JQ in python like using it through cli

Tags: python, jq

I have some cli commands that run through an api and then pass to jq like so

```sh
cat json.txt | jq '.members[] | [.name]
```

But now i am trying to do some logic in python and then pipe it out to jq, but i can't figure out how to do it even in a similar way to the above.

I read through the documentation for jq module in python, but i just can't get it to work, can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Why should your Python script have to know about that? Either pipe the output to JQ yourself (`python3 whatever.py | jq '...'`) or just write the logic you'd apply using JQ in the Python script.

Comment: You know what i didn't even think about doing it like that, good idea. But i would also like to learn how to do it within python if possible?

Comment: It is possible, you can use e.g. [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). There are [quite a few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subprocess+stdin+stdout) posts about that already.

Comment: There are at least two python wrappers for jq. Please specify which you've tried and what you've tried.

Comment: @peak i have tried the pyjq module and tried this but that just kept erroring out pyjq.all('.members[] | {"name": .name}' and then i also tried jmespath and did the following but that just returned none, jmespath.search("members[*]", data)

Comment: By the way, please follow the [mcve] guidelines; specifically, it would help to see a minimal example of json.txt

Answer (score 7):

After: `pip3 install pyjq`

the following runs without problems:

```
import pyjq
print(pyjq.all( ".members[] | [.name]", {"members": [ {"name": "foo"} ]} ))
```

### Output:

```
[['foo']]
```

### Documentation

The documentation for pyjq is at https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/

Note in particular the `url` optional argument.

Comment: why would I use this rather than https://pypi.org/project/jq/

Comment: @MrR `pyjq` seems a little more streamlined and approaching the command line use. In my case, the syntax example shown here for `pyjq` use better matches the example I  had of piping json to `jq` on the command line, and so I was easily able to convert that example to equivalent to the use of `pyjq` inside Python code without even looking further at the `pyjq` documentation. Mostly luck of the draw though I saw this before that.(Command line use of `jq` example from [here](https://github.com/pachterlab/ffq#ftp): `ffq --ftp SRR10668798 | jq -r '.[] | .url' | xargs curl -O`.)

Comment: Both solutions are similar. jq.py has been updated recently.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

sd = os.system('cat json.txt | jq ".members[] | [.name]"')

print(sd)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**There is an alternative JQ Python binding called [JQpy](https://baterflyrity.github.io/jqpy/).** This one does not require user to compile anything hence simply works on Linux/Windows/e.t.c.

### Installation

Linux:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jq
pip install jqpy
```

[Windows](https://baterflyrity.github.io/jqpy/installation.html#installation):

```bash
choco install jq
pip install jqpy
```

### Example

```py
>>> from jqpy import jq
>>> jq('.results[] | {age, city}', {
                "timestamp": 1234567890,
                "report": "Age Report",
                "results": [
                        { "name": "John", "age": 43, "city": "TownA" },
                        { "name": "Joe",  "age": 10, "city": "TownB" }
                ]
        })
[{'age': 43, 'city': 'TownA'}, {'age': 10, 'city': 'TownB'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

cmd=["cat", "json.txt", "|", "jq", "'.members[]", "|", "[.name]"]
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

print(result)
```

Comment: appreciate your response, i tested that out and it works fine, but i wanted to do the process within python like using the jq module, if anyone has any experience with using that module.